# What does the Mongo DB traffic limit mean?

Tags: mongodb

I need help interpreting this fairly ambiguous statement from the MongoDB docs:

App Services limits traffic as follows:

10,000 concurrent requests.

5,000 concurrent Device Sync connections.

Any requests made beyond the non-Sync concurrent request limit receive an HTTP response status code of
429 - Too Many Requests
. You can request a higher limit by
filing a support ticket.

Does this mean 10000 concurrent request per connection or 10000 for the cluster in total? I'm confused about this because MongoDB offers clusters with enough ram and computing power
to processes much more than 10000 request at once. Clarification from someone with decent MongoDB Expirience would be greatly Appriciated

Comment: To me this question feels more appropriate for the vendor, especially if the text already encourages filing a ticket for requesting a related change to the limits

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: App Services is serverless isn't it?

Comment: I interpreted app services as the services that MongoDB provides

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/reference/service-limitations/#request-traffic this is where it is specified in the docs